# How do I draw an arc between two lines in pgfplots using axis cs

Tags: pgfplots, arc

I would like to draw an arc between to lines in a pgfplots picture using `axis cs`. My first attempt is as follows:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}

    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=-8,xmax=8,xtick={-8,-6,...,8},
            ymin=-8,ymax=8,ytick={-8,-6,...,8},grid=major
            ,view={0}{90},x post scale={2},y post scale=2
            ]
        \addplot[black,thin,domain=0:8]{0};
        \addplot[black,thin,domain=0:8]{2.3962931*x};
        \draw [->] (axis cs:2,0) arc [radius=17mm,start angle=0,end angle=64.3];
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

However, the value of the radius and angle needed to be determined via trial and error. Hence, if I change the scaling (as used with `x post scale` and `y post scale`) then the arc does not display correctly.

Clearly, I have missed something and there should be a straight forward way to achieve my aims. I can change the arc to a circle (set radius=2 (with no units)) and I get what I expect and it scales.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Peter Johnston.

Answer (score 15):

The easiest thing to do in this case is to set `disabledatascaling`, in which case canvas and axis units are the same (i.e. `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1)` has the same effect as `\draw (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1,1)`). That will only work if your units are within a "reasonable" range that doesn't cause over- or underflows. In your case, it'll work fine. Note that you should also set `axis equal`, otherwise your arc will be squashed a bit.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}

    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=-8,xmax=8,xtick={-8,-6,...,8},
            ymin=-8,ymax=8,ytick={-8,-6,...,8},grid=major
            ,view={0}{90},x post scale={2},y post scale=2, disabledatascaling, axis equal
            ]
        \addplot[black,thin,domain=0:8]{0};
        \addplot[black,thin,domain=0:8]{2.3962931*x};
        \draw [thick, ->] (axis cs:2,0) arc [radius=2,start angle=0,end angle=64.3];
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: You could also use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\EndAngle}{atan(2.3962931)}` and use `\EndAngle` instead of 64.3 (which does not quite connect to the line).