# Specify arc radius in coordinate systems units

Tags: pgfplots, arc

This is a follow up on [Specify radius of an arc with pgfplots and axis direction cs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184381/specify-radius-of-an-arc-with-pgfplots-and-axis-direction-cs)
If I'd like to change the MWE from there to the following:

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
      xmin=-20,xmax=20,
    ]
    \addplot{x}; % not important, just to make things show up

  \end{axis}
\draw (axis cs:-16,0) arc[start angle=180, end angle=0, radius=8]; % <-- want to keep units of coordinate system here
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I specify the arc radius in axis coordinate system?
What I already tried was a solution given in [Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz) using `\pgfextractx`.
This leads to wrong lengths in my case.

Comment: You need that *inside* `axis` environment. The `axis cs:` part is not needed since pgfplots 1.11 IIRC.

Comment: You're right @Manuel. The thing is, I need to do that outside, because I have some automatically named nodes (comding from pgfplots axis environment) that are available just after the axis environment has ended. I draw some arcs based upon those points.
See the already solved question regarding this drawing order [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196641/tikz-nodes-in-pgfplots-saved-for-later-use-but-locations-mismatch](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196641/tikz-nodes-in-pgfplots-saved-for-later-use-but-locations-mismatch)

Comment: This is a little too easy for the MWE compared to your comment. Can you include your real case a little more realistic if possible?

Comment: I think though this hint is not wrong, in this case the MWE is sufficient to comply my needs. I use this in a way more complicated use case but just looking at the core of the issue, this MWE is good from my point of view. I don't want you guys having to digg deep down into my use case but rather showing a more universally approach. Hope this goes fine with most you, otherwise I have to construct another MWE. Please give me a short feedback then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values of the axis coordinate system are lost after `\end{axis}`. That means you can only access named nodes (not even `axis cs` is available here).

There are two solutions:

First, you can synchronize the unit lengths used by the axis and your picture, for example using `x=1cm, y=1cm` in the axis and in the `tikzpicture`. The axis will look differently since this overrules the scaling strategies.

Alternatively, one could try to remember the requested quantity. A way to do so might be

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
      xmin=-20,xmax=20,
      extra description/.code={%
        \pgfplotspointaxisdirectionxy{8}{8}
        \pgfgetlastxy{\X}{\Y}%
        \global\let\radiusX=\X
        \global\let\radiusY=\Y
      },
    ]
    \addplot{x}; % not important, just to make things show up

    \coordinate (P) at (axis cs:-16,0);
  \end{axis}
\draw (P) arc[start angle=180, end angle=0, x radius=\radiusX, y radius=\radiusY]; % <-- want to keep units of coordinate system here
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

My idea is to evaluate `axis direction cs` by means of the macro `\pgfplotspointaxisdirectionxy`, then I get the computed X and Y coordinates and remember them into two global macros. These are used later-on.

Comment: Awesome ,Christian. Thanks so much for taking care of my issue.
The approach you showed by code worked absolutely fine for me. I had to solve the non equal scaling of my X and Y axis with the axis option `axis equal` first.